# Generated yaml(swagger json to yaml) from Spring Swagger throws error. Doesnt get ref to Java List or Integer

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

> I am using spring Spring Fox swagger2 2.5 to get the Swagger UI. Its a spring MVC project. I am am able to get Swagger Json by hitting /v0/apidocs.
>   But when i am converting the json to yaml in swagger editor, there are errors thrown by the studio about not having the #ref of List and #ref of Integer.[This is error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHvaD.png)

Not sure how to resolve this.

```
`@DeleteMapping("/api/v0/consumers/{consumerId}/address/{addressId}")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Map<String, Integer>>> deleteByConsumerId(
        @PathVariable("consumerId") Integer consumerId, @PathVariable("addressId") Integer addressId) {

    ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Map<String, Integer>>> responseEntity = null;

    try {
        logger.debug(strConsumerId + consumerId + ", address ID: " + addressId);

        if (consumerId != null && addressId != null) {

            RestStatus status = new RestStatus("200",
                    consumerAddressDao.deleteAddressById(consumerId, addressId) + " Consumer Address Deleted ");
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(new RestResponse<Map<String, Integer>>(null, status),
                    HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error(logError, exception);
        RestStatus status = new RestStatus("500", "No Consumer address found for ID ");
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(new RestResponse<>(null, status), HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);

    }
    return responseEntity;
}
```

`

```
'@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    ApiSelectorBuilder apiBuilder = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any());'




'registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-
    ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");'
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing some annotations in your controller. Also after looking at your error it looks like the the datatypes properties generated for you are not correct. swagger don't have Integer or List, it must be 'integer' and 'array' instead. Refer Data Types section of swagger specification http://swagger.io/specification/

Comment: In java, i have to use Integer, cant use interger. I am generating the swagger json from swagger api for spring version 2.5
I see the possibility of defining a ref type of Integer, but not sure how to do it. I could literally edit the yaml but multiple people will generate the json(and will convert it to yaml) from themselves and i need to provide the solution in java code only. Thanks

Comment: Usually people define API specification using yaml/json first and use that contract/agreement to generate code using swagger code generator. You might want to try that. We are using swagger-codegen to generate API,Controller and models on the fly to keep them in sync with specification. And we then share that specification between teams, so that all teams know what API service exposes and how to consume it.